# Convert pandas dataframe into JSON format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Having the following dataframe:

```
dict_ = {'ID': 'ABC', 'CountryList': None, 'CountryList_City': None, 'City_Name': 'aaaa', 'City_Area': 22222, 'CountryList_Coordinates': None, 
         'Coordinates_X': 111, 'Coordinates_Y': 222, 'CountryList_Restaurants': None, 'Restaurants_Name': 'aaa', 'Restaurants_MenuList': None,'MenuList_Weekdays': 'bbbb', 'MenuList_Weekends': 'cccc' }

data = pd.DataFrame([dict_])
```

I need to group the common columns (note "_" showing a parent-child relationship. i.e.: "CountryList_Coordinates" would be Parent from "Coordinates_X" and "Coordinates_Y") iteratively to reach the following JSON output format:

```
{'ID': 'ABC',
 'CountryList': [
     {
         'City': {
             'Name': 'aaaa',
             'Area': 22222
          },
          'Coordinates': {
              'X': 111,
              'Y': 222
          },
          'Restaurants': {
              'Name': 'aaa',
              'MenuList':[
                  {
                  'Weekdays': 'bbbb', 
                  'Weekends': 'cccc'
                  }
              ]
          }
          },
...
 ]}
```

Columns without "_" and with None values (i.e.: CountryList) show parent values so it opens nests

I've been trying:

```
data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))

json_adapted = {}
for k, v in data_json.items():
    nested = k.split('_')
    
    if len(nested) == 1:
        json_adapted.update({k:v if v is not None else []})
    
    if len(nested) > 1:
        if nested[0] in json_adapted.keys():
            json_adapted[nested[0]].append({nested[1]: v if v is not None else 
                                            {key.split('_')[1]:val for key,val in data_json.items() if nested[1] in key.split('_') and val is not None}})
```

But fails in the last iteration resulting in:

```
{'ID': 'ABC',
 'CountryList': [{'City': {'Name': 'aaaa', 'Area': 22222}},
  {'Coordinates': {'X': 111, 'Y': 222}},
  {'Restaurants': {'Name': 'aaa'}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, I may have found a close answer.
From given example, I couldn't understand, why `CountryList` and `MenuList` are going to be array. Infact, why would there be any value of type list?

Also, I think there is spelling mistake at `Restaurant_MenuList`. As per provided result example, it should be `Restaurants_MenuList`.

Try below code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import json

# Initializing test dict object
dict_ = {'ID': 'ABC', 'CountryList': None, 'CountryList_City': None,
         'City_Name': 'aaaa', 'City_Area': 22222,
         'CountryList_Coordinates': None, 'Coordinates_X': 111,
         'Coordinates_Y': 222, 'CountryList_Restaurants': None,
         'Restaurants_Name': 'aaa', 'Restaurants_MenuList': None,
         'MenuList_Weekdays': 'bbbb', 'MenuList_Weekends': 'cccc'}


# All parent to child relationship based on '_'
# If no '_', then it's direct value
parent_child_value = defaultdict(lambda: dict())
for key, value in dict_.items():
    if value:
        if '_' in key:
            parent, child = key.split('_')
            parent_child_value[parent][child] = value
        else:
            parent_child_value[key] = value

# Creating parents and children set,
# to figure out top level keys by taking difference later
parents = set()
children = set()

# Updating parent_child_value as per relationship according to '_'
for key, value in dict_.items():
    if not value and '_' in key:
        parent, child = key.split('_')
        parent_child_value[parent][child] = parent_child_value.get(child)
        parents.add(parent)
        children.add(child)
    if value and '_' not in key:
        parents.add(key)

# Take difference to find top level keys
top_level_keys = parents.difference(children)

result = {}
# Create result by making use of top level keys
for top_level_key in list(top_level_keys):
    result[top_level_key] = parent_child_value.get(top_level_key)

# Print final result
print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

My output looks like below:

```json
{
    "ID": "ABC",
    "CountryList": {
        "City": {
            "Name": "aaaa",
            "Area": 22222
        },
        "Coordinates": {
            "X": 111,
            "Y": 222
        },
        "Restaurants": {
            "Name": "aaa",
            "MenuList": {
                "Weekdays": "bbbb",
                "Weekends": "cccc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, just fixed the spelling mistake, sorry about that. On the other hand, it should be an array as we might have many different cities in the CountryList dict, or Restaurants might have different Menus that would be included in the MenuList key.

Comment: Can you provide input example for that?

Comment: Would be the same, just imagine that i.e: in the MenuList_Weekdays you have different options bbbb, dddd as you might be able to choose among two or more different menus each day hence your output for the MenuList should look like:              'MenuList':[
                  {
                  'Weekdays': 'bbbb', 
                  'Weekends': 'cccc'
                  },                  {
                  'Weekdays': 'dddd', 
                  'Weekends': 'cccc'
                  }            
              ]

Comment: Hello @Hypnotoad, you've provided result json. Can you represent this in source json?

Comment: How do you figure out if some value is going to be array?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering. There is no source json. Source data comes from a relational data model but in order to be represented in a CSV it had to be flattened. The way I am figuring out whether some value is going to be an array is by looking at the name of the columns ending in "List" and whose values are None.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for this clarification. You've flattened the data, and in our case, it's **_dict** object. Can you provide an example of this _dict which would result in the expected output (where array contains 2 object)?

Comment: Let's see, if you take: MenuList_Weekdays. This key will appear only ones in your flat **_dict**. Therefore, even if you have list type value, list will have only 1 object.

Comment: You'll need to do that by checking common rows, so in the case we mention above " 'MenuList':[ { 'Weekdays': 'bbbb', 'Weekends': 'cccc' }, { 'Weekdays': 'dddd', 'Weekends': 'cccc' } ]" that will be grouping two different rows sharing common columns values but different ones in the Weekdays/Weekends ones.

Comment: I think you'll need to setup grouping criteria, to be able to merge multiple rows into single object. Just by appending "List" in key, you might not be able to achieve expected result, as the list is going to have only 1 object in List. Can you provide input example, showing the variations in value for multiple rows?